# Laravel 4: Join tables from different database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, join

I have a project that connects with different database, and i want to join those tables from different database using laravel 4. I searched already about this issue but i can't find the right answer. Is it possible to join tables from different database in laravel 4? If possible,does anyone can help me how to build a query for that?

Comment: You sure it's not different tables? You can't join from a different database. That's just a SQL limit.

Comment: Yes Im sure. I found this query, `SELECT u1.* FROM database1.users u1 LEFT JOIN database2.users u2 ON u1.id=u2.id WHERE u2.id IS NOT NULL;` but not in laravel 4. I want to try this query using laravel 4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do exactly that using the [DB class](http://laravel.com/docs/database):

```
$results = DB::select('select * from database1.users u1 LEFT JOIN database2.users u2 ON u1.id = u2.id WHERE u2.id = ?', array(5));
```

You can also use [Fluent](http://laravel.com/docs/queries) to build the query, which would look something like:

```
$users = DB::table('db1.users as db1')
  ->select('db1.*')
  ->leftJoin('db2.users as db2', 'db1.id', '=', 'db2.id')
  ->where('db2.id', 5)
  ->get();
```

Comment: Morgon, I have another question, where should I get the database1, database2, etc.? I know, I will just set up the database info in config file but how can I declare or call the certain database?

Comment: In this case, this would be whatever the databases are named in MySQL. If your Laravel project's database is called 'laravel' and you have data in another database called 'lookup' or something, then you'd simply substitute 'database1' and 'database2' with those values, assuming your MySQL user has access to both databases.

Comment: Hi Morgon, Thanks for the help. I tested the query and it works!